# Connection between the predual of a von Neumann algenra and $L^{\infty}(\mu)$

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I saw the following conclusion from Miguel Martin and Yoshimichi Ueda's paper.

Let $M$ be an arbitrary von Neuamnn algebra and denote its unique predual by $M_{*}$, and they are known to be non-commutative counterparts to $L_{\infty}(\mu)$ and $L_1(\mu)$, respectively.

How can we view $M_{*}$ as non-commutative counterparts to $L_{\infty}(\mu)$ and $L_1(\mu)$, respectively

Comment: The point is that, *when $M$ is commutative* then necessarily  $M=L^\infty$ and $M_*=L^1$.

Comment: But the von Neumann algebra may not be abelian.

Comment: Mammals form a class of animals that is distinguished by the possession of hair or fur, the secretion of milk by females for the nourishment of the young, and the birth of live young. Not all animals possess these features but they share many other characteristics and so could be thought of as _generalized mammals_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The category of commutative von Neumann algebras is
[contravariantly equivalent](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.05284)
to the category of compact strictly localizable enhanced measurable spaces
with morphisms being equivalence classes of measurable measure-zero reflecting
maps modulo the equivalence relation of weak equality almost everywhere.
(Here “compact” is an abstract measure-theoretic analogue of Radon measures,
and “strictly localizable” generalizes σ-finiteness.)

Under this correspondence, commutative von Neumann algebras
are precisely algebras of bounded measurable functions
on compact strictly localizable enhanced measurable spaces,
modulo equality almost everywhere.
Preduals of commutative von Neumann algebras
are precisely the vector spaces of finite complex-valued measures on such spaces,
or, equivalently, L^1-spaces with respect to any faithful measure.

Thus, it is completely natural to see the predual of a noncommutative
von Neumann algebra as the vector space of measures
on a noncommutative measurable space.

Comment: I don't undersatnd the last sentence. Why can we  view the predual of a non-commutative von Neumann algebra as the vector space of measures on a commutative measurable space?

Comment: @mathbeginner: It says “noncommutative”, not “commutative”.  The point of the entire answer was that the algebraic constructions continue to make sense if the commutativity assumption is dropped.  For instance, the integral ∫ f dμ can be expressed as f(μ), i.e., the result of evaluation of f, considered as a linear functional on the predual, on the element μ.  This continues to make sense in the noncommutative case, and one can prove nontrivial theorems based on this intuition.

Comment: Woould you mind recommending some reference books or papers on the proof of the theorem?

Comment: @mathbeginner: Which one?  If you are referring to the theorem stated in the first paragraph of my answer, the hyperlink there will take you to the paper that proves it.